# what database design for CRFs?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am actually working on a project that involves the managing of the E-CRFs (electronic case report forms) ay you may know, CRFs are documents used by researchers to collect data by asking several questions and having their answers on paper.

To make a web interface that releaves the reaserchers from paper work.

My question concerns the design of the database. the ECRFs are not static, if they were, I would have to create a simple table in the database and every field would correspond to a question in the CRF. but what I want is to have a database that allows me to create my own CRF with variable number of fields everytime, or even from a same CRF I could have updates in which I add or retrieve a field.

How do I proceed for the database design ??
thank you.

Comment: You should not limit yourself to relational databases... consider NoSQL options for this kind of thing

Answer (score 0):

Use a relational database only to store your metadata (e.g. who filled in the form) and store the rest in XML or JSON format in a BLOBS or flat files.

Comment: can you give more explanation please